# Allow user to pick a location

Tags: location

I would like to add a field to my node that allows the user to search for a location like a city and pinpoint that location on the map or pick a location on a map but without having to zoom in from viewing the whole world (like the problem I am having using the geofield).
Cheers

Comment: why have all the answers from the question been deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geolocation field module solved this problem.